# Routing ASP.NET MVC application with attribute routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, attributerouting

I have started working with AttributeRouting for an [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) 4 application to manage its routes, and I must say it's an excellent library. I am very impressed with the localization feature with it where I can have localized routes very easily. I have two questions:

1. My application will be supporting a large number of languages, 20+. There could be 30 or so different localized values - any performance concerns with such numbers?
2. When a route gets resolved to a controller action, is it possible to set the threads culture at this point with language being navigated to? Along with this, I would like to do some customization at the point the route is resolved to the controller action (same point thread culture is set). Is this possible?